# Python3 : Print returned values from the function in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyterhub

I am working on a Jupyterhub project and beginner Python user. I would like to print returned values from the function in another `py` file for dubug.

`a.py`:

```
class TestSpawner(SlurmSpawner):
    def _options_form_default(self):
        return """
        <label for="queue">node type</label>
        <select name="queue">
          <option value="standard">standard</option>
          <option value="dev-test">TEST</option>
        </select>
        <label for="runtime">Job duration</label>
        <select name="runtime">
          <option value="1:00:00">1 hour</option>
          <option value="2:00:00">2 hours</option>
        </select>
        """
    def options_from_form(self, formdata):
        print ( formdata.get('queue', [''])[0].strip())
        options = {}
        options['queue'] = formdata.get('queue', [''])[0].strip()
        options['runtime'] = formdata.get('runtime', [''])[0].strip()
        print (options)
        return options
```

`b.py`:

```
import sys
from a import *
print (options)
print (queue)
```

I can see the queue and options values using `print (options)` in `a.py`, but I am not sure how I can print the values in `b.py` and make sure it gets correct values from `a.py`. Please help me and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Import your module, make an instance, and call the method in `b.py`:

```
import a

spawner = a.TestSpawner()

formdata = 'my form data'  # add your data here
print(options_from_form(formdata))
```